# Send SMS using HP UFT 12.02

Tags: vba, vbscript, outlook, qtp, hp-uft

I have a requirement of sending SMS to single/multiple users in case of any failure while executing a UFT automation script.
I have used below code & updated the smtp server name to the one I found in Outlook Account settings.Below code is failing with error "At least one recipient is required but none were found".

Please help me resolve this issue. Also note that I cannot use any free SMS API due to access restrictions

```
Set objMessage = CreateObject("CDO.Message") 
objMessage.Subject = "Test Failed" 
objMessage.Sender = "test@domain.com" 
objMessage.To = "+91XXXXXXXXXX" 
objMessage.TextBody = "Test XYZ failed at: " & Now 
'Configuration information for the remote SMTP server. 
objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item _ 
("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2 
'Name or IP of Remote SMTP Server 
objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item _ 
("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = "Server 
 name" 
'Server port 
objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item _ 
("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = 25 
objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Update 
objMessage.Send 
Set objMessage = Nothing
```

Comment: Is there any way to send SMS from office communicator API in vbscript?

Answer (score -1):

*CDO.Message uses SMTP!*

**SMTP**

First of all you should know what SMPT is and for what it stands!

SMTP is a communication protocol for the transmission of E-Mails. Communication takes place between an e-mail client and an SMTP-Server or between two SMTP-Servers.
[image]

In addition to SMTP, there are two other protocols for E-Mail exchange with POP and IMAP. However, these two protocols are only used to fetch or manage E-Mail. SMTP, on the other hand, is a communication protocol that can receive and forward emails.

> SMTP stands for **Simple Mail Transfer Protocol**.

---

**Your Problem**

You want to send Messages with HP UFT and you are trying to do this with SMTP. But now we know this isn't possible

---

**Answer:** It isn't possible to send SMS over HP UFT.

Comment: OP has stated "note that I cannot use any free SMS API due to access restrictions" and you have simply explained SMTP (which was not asked), and then provided a link (link-only answers are discouraged here, you should include the actual content) to using an API (which isn't even free)... Saying it is not possible should be a comment not an answer